# Laravel Model Accessor and Mutator with wildcard (*)

Tags: php, laravel, wildcard, accessor, mutators

**The issue**

I would like to set accessors and mutators for one model attribute but with wildcards
I have attribute stored for different languages called tags_en, tags_es, Tags_fr, etc.. for (8) language tags

I would like to set one accessor and one mutator in the Tag model for all of the 8 language sub-types ***once*** instead of using couple of accessor/mutator method for each of them.

Normally one would do the following for each of them e.g. tags_en

```
public function getTagsEnAttribute($tags){
    return join(', ', json_decode($tags));
}

public function setTagsEnAttribute($tags){
    $this->attributes['tags_en'] =
        json_encode(
            array_map('trim', explode(',', $tags))
        );
}
```

Then I have to repeat them for each language variety of tags which are at the moment 8 languages which is not practical.

**My Objective**

Any way to do accessors and mutators with a wildcard something like (which of course do not work this way):

```
public function getTagsWildcardAttribute($tags){
    return join(', ', json_decode($tags));
}
```

**or**

something like:

```
foreach ($tagsAttributes as $TagAttribute){
    //method building code for each tags language
}
```

**Similar Laravel idea exists for Validation with wildcard**

I assume that there may be a way to do it through laravel Model class using wildcard. This is similar to Validator where you can validate each element of an array like this:

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [ 
    'person.*.email' => 'email|unique:users', 
    'person.*.first_name' => 'required_with:person.*.last_name', 
]);
```

**Questions:**

1. If these model ***accessors and mutators with wild card*** are not available in current laravel framework - do you agree with me that this is worthwhile to ***add*** in the next laravel versions?
2. If so, then ***how to ask laravel makers, officially, to consider this in the upcoming versions***?
3. Can Stackoverflow staff to ask laravel builders for that improvement (if they see it is) in our behalf?

Comment: Do they need to be accessors & mutators? Is there a reasong you can’t just methods on the model?

Comment: I would prefer to use the laravel framework methods available for models than to re-invent the wheel - of course I assume that there may be a way to do it through laravel Model class. This is similar to Validator where you can validate each element of an array like this:

    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'person.*.email' => 'email|unique:users',
        'person.*.first_name' => 'required_with:person.*.last_name',
    ]);

Comment: I'm a bit confused: do you actually have all of these as columns in your db: `tags_en`, `tags_es`, etc? Or do you just have one JSON column named `tags`?

Comment: I have all these columns in the table as I need to view them in blade under separate tab-groups each for different language.

Comment: The I think my solution will work for you. Please see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could extend `castAttribute()` and `setAttribute()` methods.

```
protected function castAttribute($key, $value) {
        if (is_null($value)) {
            return $value;
        }

        if ($this->isTagCastable($key)) {
            return join(', ', json_decode($value));
        }

        return parent::castAttribute($key, $value);
    }

public function setAttribute($key, $value)
{
    if ($this->isTagCastable($key)) {
        $this->attributes[$key] =
            json_encode(
                array_map('trim', explode(',', $value))
            );
    }

    return parent::setAttribute($key, $value);
}

protected function isTagCastable($key) {
    return preg_match('/tags_[a-z]{2}/', $key);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit unclear to me as to how your Database is setup, but from what I understand, it has a table with columns named `tags_en`, `tags_fr`, `tags_de`, etc.

Here's an idea:

1. Add a property that holds the columns you want to set/get
2. Create a custom type in `$casts`
3. Override the `boot()` method and use it to set the tagson `creating` and `updating`
4. Override the `castAttribute($key, $value)` method and use it to cast the value back when you retrieve it (this will function like an accessor)

It would look something like this

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class MyModel extends Model
{
    protected static $tags = [
        'tags_en',
        'tags_fr',
        'tags_de',
    ];

    public static function boot()
    {
        static::creating(function ($model) {
            foreach (static::$tags as $tag) {
                // You can customize exactly what you need to do here
                $model->$tag = json_encode($model->tag);
            }

            unset($model->tag);
        });

        static::updating(function ($model) {
            foreach (static::$tags as $tag) {
                // You can customize exactly what you need to do here
                $model->$tag = json_encode($model->tag);
            }

            unset($model->tag);
        });

        parent::boot();
    }

    /**
     * Cast an attribute to a native PHP type.
     *
     * @param  string  $key
     * @param  mixed  $value
     * @return mixed
     */
    protected function castAttribute($key, $value)
    {
        if (in_array($key, static::$tags)) {
            return join(', ', (array) json_decode($value));
        }

        parent::castAttribute($key, $value);
    }
}
```

When you create an instance of the model:

```
$t = App\MyModel::create([
    'name' => 'My Tags',
    'tag' => ['key' => 'value', 'key2' => 'value2']
]);
```

Then when you retrieve an instance:

```
$t = App\MyModel::find($id);
echo $t->tags_en; // This will be handled by the `castAttribute($key, $value)` override
```

Regarding your last 3 questions: If you think it should be included, then the best thing is to a) ask via the GitHub repo or even better b) code it up and put in a PR. Stack Overflow staff has nothing to do with Laravel so they can't and won't and wouldn't be able to do anything.

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution for that, **Eloquent Mutators** https://github.com/topclaudy/eloquent-mutators

After installing the package, you would be able to register custom accessors/mutators extensions for your Eloquent models.